# How do I get the hash name and key in TCL?

Tags: arrays, hash, tcl, key-value

I'm trying to figure out how to get the hash name and key in the following situation. Say I have the following hash value:

```
set CLIENT(CAR) "Koenigsegg"
```

If I pass `$CLIENT(CAR)` into a proc, the value that is passed is "Koenigsegg". Is there a way to also capture the fact that the hash and key storing that value is 'CLIENT' and 'CAR', respectively?

For example:

```
proc foobar {item} {
  set the_item $item 
}

foobar $CLIENT(CAR)
```

In this example, the proc only receives the value of $CLIENT(CAR), which is "koenigsegg". The `$item` is "koenigsegg", but I don't know what kind of item it is. I'd like to get the hash name "CLIENT" and key "CAR" to know that "koenigsegg" it is a "client car".

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the name of the array into a proc, then use `upvar` to access it:

```
proc process_array {arrayName} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName myArray
    puts "Car is $myArray(CAR)"
}

set CLIENT(CAR) "Koenigsegg"
process_array CLIENT ;# Pass the name of the array, note: no dollar sign
```

Output:

```
Car is Koenigsegg
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

## Update

So, you want to pass two things into the proc: the hash name (Tcl refers to it as "array") and the index name (CAR):

```
proc process_array {arrayName index} {
    upvar 1 $arrayName myArray
    puts "My array is $arrayName"
    puts "List of indices: [array names myArray]"
    puts "Car is $myArray($index)"
}

set CLIENT(CAR) "Koenigsegg"
process_array CLIENT CAR;# Pass the name of the array, note: no dollar sign
```

Output:

```
My array is CLIENT
List of indices: CAR
Car is Koenigsegg
```

## Update 2

It seems that the original poster (OP) is asking for something like this:

```
process_array $CLIENT(CAR)
```

and expect the proc `process_array` to figure out the name of the array (`CLIENT`) and the index (`CAR`). This is not possible in my knowledge. When Tcl interpreter encounters the line above, it evaluates the `$CLIENT(CAR)` expression and the line becomes:

```
process_array Koenigsegg
```

That means within `process_array`, the proc has no idea about any array. All it knows is someone has passed to it a string *"Koenigsegg"*.

Now, if you pass into the proc the name of the array, then it can figure out the array's name, any any indices the array has. Please see my previous code.

Comment: I actually want to get the hash and key name "CLIENT" and "CAR". I've added an example to my post.

Comment: Seems like there's some problem with the code. I changed some stuff to, namely: `puts "My array is $arrayName"`, `process_array CLIENT CAR` and `puts "List of indices: [array names myArray]"`. Is that what was originally intended?

Comment: Yes. Thank you to Jerry. I meant to type the dollar sign, but on the keyboard for iPad mini, it came out as the hash sign. The next two mistake were purely mine.

Comment: That still requires me to know the index 'CAR' beforehand. I simply want to pass into the proc $CLIENT(CAR), and be able to somehow obtain the hash and key name 'CLIENT' and 'CAR' in the proc itself.

Comment: Please see my **Update 2**

Comment: Your update #2 is exactly what I'm asking about. I figured it wasn't possible to obtain that data directly, but I was hoping I'd get some feedback on some indirect solutions that might work. Thanks for your help @HaiVu!